# Get column names, distinct values and its occurrences into a text file with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark Scala and would like to execute the following tasks:

1. Get all column names, the values and its occurrences from a table
2. Write the result into a text file, i.e. in the following format:

   ```
   Column Name |Value | Occurrences    
      Col1     |Test  |      12       
      Col2     |123   |      15
   ```

I am using Spark 1.6, not Spark 2.0.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Cheers,
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. 
Let me explain with an example.

I have a file, users.txt with content as following:

```
1 abc@test.com EN US

2 xyz@test2.com EN GB

3 srt@test3.com FR FR
```

Code:

```
var fileRDD=sc.textFile("users.txt")    
case class User(ID:Int,email:String,lang:String,country:String)
var rawRDD=fileRDD.flatMap(_.split("\t")).map(_.split(" ")) 
var userRDD=rawRDD.map(u=>User(u(0).toInt,u(1).toString,u(2).toString,u(3).toString))
userDF.registerTempTable("user_table")

sqlContext.sql("select * from user_table").show()

+---+-------------+----+-------+    
| ID|        email|lang|country|    
+---+-------------+----+-------+    
|  1| abc@test.com|  EN|     US|    
|  2|xyz@test2.com|  EN|     GB|    
|  3|srt@test3.com|  FR|     FR|    
+---+-------------+----+-------+


var emailCount=sqlContext.sql("select 'email' as col,email as value, count(email) as occur from user_table group by email")     
var langCount=sqlContext.sql("select 'lang' as col,lang as value, count(lang) as occur from user_table group by lang")    
emailCount.unionAll(langCount).show()


+-----+-------------+-----+    
|  col|        value|occur|    
+-----+-------------+-----+    
|email|srt@test3.com|    1|    
|email|xyz@test2.com|    1|    
|email| abc@test.com|    1|    
| lang|           EN|    2|    
| lang|           FR|    1|    
+-----+-------------+-----+
```